# I can't install textract on windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, ocr

I'm trying to install textract on a windows 10 machine for an OCR project, but when  using *pip install textract*, the istallation fails with the following error message:

```css
(OcrEnv) C:\Users\Toshiba>pip install textract
Collecting textract
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/00/a9278b3672a31da06394eb588a16e96f8fce9f6ae0ed44cca18103d4aef5/textract-1.6.1.tar.gz
Collecting argcomplete==1.8.2 (from textract)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/0f/f965f1520e6ba24b63320919eecfbe3d03debd32402e0c61a08e8fa02d17/argcomplete-1.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: chardet==2.3.0 in c:\users\toshiba\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from textract) (2.3.0)
Collecting python-pptx==0.6.5 (from textract)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/9c/30bc244cedc571307efe0780d8195ffed5b08f09c94d23f50d6d5144ebc7/python-pptx-0.6.5.tar.gz
Collecting docx2txt==0.6 (from textract)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/aa/72/f02730ec3b0219d8f783a255416339b02ff8b6a300c817abf0505833212a/docx2txt-0.6.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4==4.5.3 in c:\users\toshiba\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from textract) (4.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: xlrd==1.0.0 in c:\users\toshiba\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from textract) (1.0.0)
Collecting EbookLib==0.15 (from textract)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/04/30/2cbf65fa9587a1ecc66a78eea91f9189ead8fdadd5e009115bce34529aa6/EbookLib-0.15.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-y9tbwmrn\EbookLib\setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        long_description = open('README.md').read(),
      File "c:\users\toshiba\anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 1671: character maps to <undefined>

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-y9tbwmrn\EbookLib\
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an issue with one of `textract`'s dependencies, `ebooklib`. `textract` is requiring *exactly* version 0.15. The workaround described in this issue is to install `Conda` and `Swig`, then clean up a Unicode character in the README so that `pip` can build a version of 0.15 that will work:

```
# Run in Python 3.x
with open(r"C:\Users\franc\OneDrive\Pukeko\EbookLib-0.15\README.md", "rb") 
as f:
    text = f.read().decode('ascii', 'replace')

with open(r"C:\Users\franc\OneDrive\Pukeko\EbookLib-0.15\README.md", "w") 
as f:
    print(text, file=f)
```

You will need to change those paths appropriately to match your machine.

Others have had some difficulties getting this to work, so you may need to ask in that issue if you continue to have problems.

[Issue is here.](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract/issues/194)

Comment: Thank you Joe! this was very helpful